# Python regex problem

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match any of the following lines with a regex in python:

```
RAA RAA

RAA RAA / OOO OOO

RAA RAA / OOO OOO / ROCKY
```

These strings should always be on their own line so `RAA RAA moves over there.` wouldn't match.

I came up with this regex using RegExr:

```
^([A-Z]*([ ]?)*([A-Z]?)*([ \/]?)*)*$
```

This works fine to match all the different lines however it causes python to hang if it tries to match `RAA RAA moves over there.`

I've no idea why. Are there any regex experts that might have some insight?

Comment: Define "hangs" - how long did you wait? Also note that one-char character classes are redundant and `*` implies `?` (for instance, `([ ]?)*` is `\ *` sans the backslash, which I was forced to include because markdown sometimes tries too hard not to obscure non-mark'd-up text).

Comment: Are you just trying to match lines consisting only of upper case letters, forward slashes and spaces? It's not clear to me what property you are after?

Comment: You've said "match any of these (three) lines", and then given us a regexp which matches much more. Please be more specific about the requirements.

Comment: -1 for again giving us only specific examples and no pattern or description in a question about regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entire pattern is full of optional matches, which is likely causing lots of backtracking, and thus the hanging experience. Try using a mandatory match where it makes sense, such as:

```
^([A-Z]+([ ]?)+([A-Z])*([ /])*)*$
```

A cleaner pattern, without the unnecessary capturing groups, would be:

```
^([A-Z]+[ ]?)+([A-Z]+[ /]*)*$
```

Notice that the use of `+` instead of `*` ensures that at least one character must match, rather than making the entire pattern optional and taxing the regex engine.

Comment: This is definitely what I need. My regex skills are woefully inadequate so this advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That regex is far too general:  not only does it match more than you want, but it has so many `*`s that the regex matcher will constantly be pointlessly backtracking to try some other combination.  I haven't tried to work the combinatorial tree, but it's at least several thousand attempts per non-matching line.

Specific is better, and making sure you don't backtrack over what you're committed to is better:

```
^RAA RAA(?: \/ OOO OOO(?: \/ ROCKY)?)?$
```

If the substrings aren't constant, you should specify them as completely as possible to avoid unnecessary backtracking.

(The `?:` are another small optimization:  don't record the parenthesized matches for later extraction.  If you do need the substrings, my guess is you don't want the `/`s with them, so capture just the parts you want.)